# Binding a Grid to a tap command

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I've got a `Grid` which contains some objects and one of them is a `Button`.
The button has its own `Command` binding and everything's fine.

I've added a binding to the `Grid`'s tap event but now its `Command` gets executed even if I tap on the `Button`.

Since I'm using MVVM Light, I've got the possibility to use `PassEventArgsToCommand` to get a `GestureEventArgs` in my code and check the source of the event before actually doing anything.

The problem is that this parameter is always `null` in my method, so I can't do anything with it.

Is there any way to exclude my `Button` from executing this `Command`?
Something like a `CanExecute` function that returns false for the `Button` type.

EDIT:

XAML code for the `Grid`

```
<Grid Height="100" Margin="15,0,15,17" Tag="{Binding ServiceId}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">                        
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=DetailsCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Poster}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="100" Width="100"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Directors[0]}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Genres}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Year}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource StarButton}" Command="{Binding SelectCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you show your xaml for the grid and it's children

Comment: I've added the requested xaml

Comment: can you explain why you want to capture the grid's tap event.  I had a similar problem with a focus visual event and a button, but it will depend on your scenario if it works

Comment: Basically I'd like to handle the tap on a `LongListSelector` item